# Vertically align symbols and text

Tags: css

I have the word STARS followed by 5 stars (`&#9733;`)

The problem I have is that the stars are smaller than the word and I want them to vertically align, but can't figure out how.

Here's what I'm trying: [Fiddle here too](https://jsfiddle.net/p357agt2/)

```css
html, body {
  font-size: 100%; /* for our beloved IE */
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  color: #333;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height:1em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.stars {
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  vertical-align: middle; /* <-- I thought this would do it */
}
```

```html
<h3>STARS <span class="stars">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span></h3>
```

Comment: Your stars appear vertically centered to my eye.  Maybe it's rendering different for you, but on my Mac (OS Mavericks 10.9.5) in Firefox 37.0.1, it rendered vertically centered.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p357agt2/1/ This kinda works, even though it’s `vertical-align:top;`…

Comment: Found the reason: the `line-height` is interfering and making things weird!

Comment: @Xufox Would you mind making a demo of that? It might develop into the best answer yet.

Comment: @showdev A demo of what? Without the `line-height`? If you’d remove `line-height` from `h3` and otherwise wrote it like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p357agt2/1) then `vertical-align` would work like expected. Problem is: who knows what would happen if `line-height` got removed? Looking at you, Internet Explorer!

Comment: @Xufox Yeah, exactly. Thanks. I was hoping you'd make an answer out of it though.

Comment: Just to clear up any misleading info for future readers: it turns out the main issue is not `line-height` but the fact that _STARS_ isn’t wrapped inside a `<span>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just put a `position: relative` on there and bump them up a bit.

This is something you should not do often (messing with positions can make your page flow messy fast if you don't know what you're doing), but it works for little situations like yours:

```css
html, body {
  font-size: 100%; /* for our beloved IE */
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  color: #333;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height:1em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.stars {
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  position: relative;
  bottom: .1em; /* em will make it work at any font size, thanks Xufox*/
}
```

```html
<h3>STARS <span class="stars">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span></h3>
```

Adjust to your preference. I only put a .1em bump up because I think that looks best at various font sizes, but you fiddle around with it till you like it.

---

As for why the `vertical-align` didn't work, it's because that property only acts on `inline` elements, see **Rick Hitchcock**'s answer for more detail on that. The `h3` isn't an inline block so there's nothing to align the `span` with!

While you could change the displays around to make this work properly it's not really what you want for your situation. The position is better suited to aligning icons (like font-awesome icons) with the text next to them.

Comment: To be fair, this is the simplest method to achieve the end result. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, if `bottom` could be recalculated in such a way that the value would be in `em` instead of `px` it would be better because then it’d be independent from font size.

Comment: It works, but I'd still like to know more about why `vertical-align` isn't working as expected.

Comment: @showdev As I said in the comments above: if both texts were wrapped with `<span>` tags and both had `display:inline-block` then `vertical-margin:middle` would only work without `line-height` set on `h3`.

Comment: True @Xufox. It would be better with `em`. I'll add that

Comment: @Xufox Yes, but I'm trying to understand *why* that works and why the OP's original code doesn't. Not just a solution, but an explanation.

Comment: @showdev Ok, now I’ve posted an answer as well. Turns out it’s something different entirely…

Answer (score 3):

`vertical-align` will work, if you add `display:table-cell` or `display:inline-block` and wrap your text in a `<span>` with the same display-property

```css
html, body {
  color: #333;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.text {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
.stars {
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 0.6;
    font-size: .2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <span class="text">STARS</span>
  <span class="stars">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
</h3>
```

Comment: Ahem… it affects at least `display:inline-block` as well.

Comment: Yes. When I change `vertical-align`, the position changes.

Comment: Just for confirmation, w3.org says [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) applies to ["inline-level"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-level) elements, which includes elements set to `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Note that it's the bottom margin – *not* the vertical-align – that is making this centered.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Yeah, true. Any idea why it doesn't look centered with `vertical-align` only?

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood explained it well: "The h3 isn't an inline block so there's nothing to align the span with!"

Comment: @RickHitchcock But it [still doesn't center](http://jsfiddle.net/2qkqnu0o/1/) even if the `<h3>` *is* `inline-block`.

Comment: That's true.  This is a head-scratcher.

Comment: I agree. Seems to [work better if they are not nested](http://jsfiddle.net/2qkqnu0o/3/).

Comment: Ok, I'll take a wild guess here: Maybe the `<span>` is in a different line-box? Is there such a thing as nested line-boxes?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem by making the `h3` a table row and `.stars` a table cell.

According to the [table height algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout), when you use `vertical-align: middle` on a table cell:

> The center of the cell is aligned with the center of the rows it
>   spans.

Add these styles:

```
h3 {
  display: table-row;
}

.stars {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
html, body {
  font-size: 100%; /* for our beloved IE */
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  color: #333;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height:1em;
  font-weight: 100;
  display: table-row;
}

.stars {
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<h3>STARS <span class="stars">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span></h3>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it *all* out: https://jsfiddle.net/p357agt2/2/.

There were a few things on which the rendering engine had a different opinion of rendering things than you. I managed to make a [reduced example](http://jsfiddle.net/3362qdbr/2/) of your layout:

First of all: note the word *STARS* being wrapped in a `<span>` element.

```
<h3>
  <span>STARS</span><span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
</h3>
```

Then: these are the minimally required rules for this to work.

```css
span{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
span:first-child{
  font-size:40px;
}
span:last-child{
  font-size:12px;
}
```

**So what I changed in your JSFiddle is**:

1. I removed that `margin-bottom` rule entirely
2. I removed the `vertical-align` rule *from the `stars` class*
3. I wrapped the word *STARS* in a `<span>` element
4. I applied `vertical-align:middle` to *any* `span` in an `h3`: `h3 span`
5. (Optional) I applied `margin-left:.3em;` to `.stars` to produce a little gap between *STARS* and *★★★★★*¹

Basically the text node *STARS* **needed** to be inside a `<span>` for this to work. Then `vertical-align` needed to be applied to **both**.

**Full code**:

```css
html, body {
  font-size: 100%; /* for our beloved IE */
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  color: #333;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height:1em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.stars {
  margin-left: .3em;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
h3 span{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <span>STARS</span><span class="stars">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
</h3>
```

As far as I know this fix changes your layout, code and standard rendering (e. g. those `display:table-cell` work arounds) the least.

---

1: You could also get a space by having a line break between the two `<span>` nodes in the source code but it looks weird when selected…

Comment: Neat! Good job! But isn't this a bit verbose for something so small? What's the advantage over `position`?

Comment: Was the problem related to the fact that the sibling to the span was a text node an not an element of its own? So two sibling elements can be aligned but an element and a text node cannot?

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood I feel that `position` is a bit hacky… if you wanna _center something vertically_, you’d think you’d need `vertical-align:middle` instead of some accurately calculated `position`. `vertical-align` basically calculates the position for you.

Comment: @showdev Yes, it turns out this was the main issue.

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood But still… `position:relative; top:`…`em;` still _can_ be applied in some cases of course. It’s not outlawed or anything.

Answer (score -1):

See the inline style attributes I added below to demonstrate how to fix it.

I used inline styles to demonstrate - you'd want to extract those to your own style sheet.

```
<h3>
   <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">STARS</span>
   <span class="stars" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
</h3>
```

Note: I wrapped the title text with a span to make it work. You need two inline-block elements side by side to align something vertically this way.

Note: You'll also want to add some padding between the two spans.

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p357agt2/16/

Comment: Can’t confirm that it works. Could you include a JSFiddle? Or does this work only with the [original JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p357agt2/)? Then it’s only dependent on `margin-bottom: 6px !important;`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn’t really the correct solution as it doesn’t really center the texts. It’s solely dependent on `margin-bottom: 6px !important;`.

Comment: @Xufox That's not quite right. I incorrectly assigned center to the vertical-align property. I fixed that and updated the fiddle and removed the margin; it's not needed. Thank you however for pointing it out. I would not have noticed my mistake. The elements center correctly now.